# SQL count column from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, subquery, aggregate-functions

I have two tables in a database

The first being `people` which has the columns

```
id: int,
name: varchar(10)
```

and another being `relationships` which represents a one way following

```
me: int
following: int
```

Where `me` and `following` are foreign keys that match the `id` primary key on the person in table `people`.

I want to run a query that given a `id` of a person returns their name and the count of people that they are following and the number who are following them.

My current attempt is

```sql
SELECT *, COUNT(following.me), COUNT(following.following) FROM people
WHERE id = 3
JOIN following f1 on f1.me = id
JOIN following f2 on f2.following = id;
```

But it is throwing in error about the where syntax. I think I need to use `group by` somewhere but I am struggling as to how that works over multiple tables.

So say given `id=2` it would return `[{name: "sam", followers: 4, following: 3}]`

Comment: Try putting the `WHERE id = 3` part at the end, after the `JOIN`s?

Comment: You can't reference a table by it's named if you've aliased it. You alias the table `f1` by then try to reference `following` in the `SELECT`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could be solved simply with inline correlated subqueries, like:

```
select 
    p.name,
    (select count(*) from relationships r where r.following = p.id) followers,
    (select count(*) from relationships r where r.me = p.id) following
from people p
where p.id = 3
```

This should be a quite efficient option.

Otherwise, starting from your existing query, you can also `left join` and aggregate:

```
select 
    p.name,
    count(distinct r.following) followers,
    count(distinct r.me) following
from people p
left join relationships r on p.id in (r.followers, r.me)
where p.id = 2
group by p.id, p.name
```

Answer (score 1):

Your attempt will not work (even with correct syntax) because `COUNT()` returns the number of non-NULL values.  After the `JOIN`, any column with no `NULL` values will return the same result.

Although you *could* fix it with `COUNT(DISTINCT)`, I would recommend correlated subqueries for this:

```
select p.*,
       (select count(*)
        from relationships r
        where r.me = p.id
       ) as num_followed,
       (select count(*)
        from relationships r
        where r.following = p.id
       ) as num_following
from people p;
```

You can also do this by preaggregating:

```
select p.*, fe.num_followed, fi.num_following
from people p left join
     (select r.me, count(*) as num_followed
      from relationships r
      group by r.me
     ) fe
     on fe.me = p.id left join
     (select r.following, count(*) as num_followed
      from relationships r
      group by r.follwoing
     ) fi
     on fi.following = p.id ;
```

Answer (score 1):

`Group by id, name` the double join of the table `people` to the table `relationships` and count the distinct `me` and `following`:

```
SELECT p.id, p.name,
  COUNT(DISTINCT f1.following) counterfollowers, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT f2.me) counterfollowing
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN relationships f1 on f1.me = p.id
LEFT JOIN relationships f2 on f2.following = p.id
WHERE p.id = 3
GROUP BY p.id, p.name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=562d67ac024acb4a955304c732b71473).
Results:

```
> id | name | counterfollowers | counterfollowing
> -: | :--- | ---------------: | ---------------:
>  3 | c    |                2 |                1
```

Answer (score 0):

We can try using two separate subqueries to find the two following counts:

```
SELECT
    p.name,
    COALESCE(r1.me_cnt, 0) AS following,
    COALESCE(r2.following_cnt, 0) AS followers
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT me, COUNT(*) AS me_cnt
    FROM relationships
    GROUP BY me
) r1
    ON r1.me = p.id
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT following, COUNT(*) AS following_cnt
    FROM relationships
    GROUP BY following
) r2
    ON r2.following = p.id;
```